# Generate all combination of elements in table (langage C)

Tags: c, codeblocks, apriori

i have i table of integer

```
int Table[]={1,2,3,....,28};
```

i want to have this combination:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 28
```

and after i will have this

```
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 23 24 24 .....
```

until to have all combination possible without repetition `(i.e 12=21)`

I want combination like they are made in excel columns for example

```
char alp[26]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P'
,'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
```

Comment: It seems you're looking for *permutations* of the array. There are many algorithms for doing unique permutations of arrays. I suggest you search for some and try them yourself.

Comment: Also, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That `26` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem can be solved like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swp(char* array, int index_1, int index_2)
{
    char tmp = array[index_1];
    array[index_1] = array[index_2];
    array[index_2] = tmp;
}

void perm(char* array, int start, int end)
{
    if (start == end)
        printf("%s\n", array);
    else
    {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            swp(array, start, i);
            perm(array, start + 1, end);
            swp(array, start, i);
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    char s[] = "Banana";
    perm(s, 0, 5);
}
```

We basically start with swapping the first Elemen with other elements, we use the loop so every choice we could do in the first swap is computed in the end.
When we do one iteration, say swapping the first element with itself in the very first iteration, we call perm() recursively and continue on that decision, after we return from the recursion we have to undo the swap so the untouched array can proceed the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion swap element with all possible following elements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* array, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

void print_array(int *array, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<len; i++ )
    {
         printf("%c ", array[i]);
    };
    printf("\n");   
}

void permute(int *array, int start, int len)
{
    int i;
    if(start == len)
    {
        print_array(array, len);
        return;
    }

    permute(array, start + 1, len);

    for(i = start + 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(array[start] == array[i])
            continue;

        swap(array, start, i);

        permute(array, start + 1, len);
        swap(array, start, i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // for 4 elements:
    int perm[] = {'A','B','C','D'};
    int number_of_elements = 4;

    permute(perm, 0, number_of_elements);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
A B C D 
A B D C 
A C B D 
A C D B 
A D C B 
A D B C 
B A C D 
B A D C 
B C A D 
B C D A 
B D C A 
B D A C 
C B A D 
C B D A 
C A B D 
C A D B 
C D A B 
C D B A 
D B C A 
D B A C 
D C B A 
D C A B 
D A C B 
D A B C
```

Comment: thank you for this code it will help me , but for your example i want this result :
`A `
`B` 
`C `
`D` 
`A B // i don't want`
`B A because it is the same `
`A C // i don't want `
`C A because it is the same `
`A D `
`A B C ///i don't want A C B because it containt the same alphabet `
`A B D` 
`A C D `
`A B C D // all combinations contains this alphabet are the sale so i don't want it` 

 i hope you can understand me , sorry for my explanation – Abderrahmane 6 mins ago